# Dynamics CRM: Model Driven App: When showing Custom Page as pop up Dialog, formatting error occurs

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, powerapps-modeldriven, custom-pages

I am working with Microsoft Dynamics CRM and have a question.

I want to show a custom page as a pop up dialog in an entity form. So far, I am able to show it, but the formatting is broken. It looks like everything is on top of each other:

[image: Result of broken formatting]

While checking, I saw that every element in the edit form (contained in the custom page) have its CSS `position` set to `Absolute`. This seems to be the problem here. The next picture confirms it. I changed the `Top` value of one of the element and got the following result:

[image]

Now, after having had a look into it, my question is the following:
Could you tell me, how exactly do I have to configure the editing form in the custom page to get the correct result (in the page designer)? I am also open for a JavaScript - solution. But I am not sure how to run it in this type of context.

[Designer:Left side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fuCoI.png)

[Designer:right side 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LUIcM.png)

[Designer: right side 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IoqY5.png)

Comment: you are most probably calling your custom page via Js. You might want to open your custom page as centered dialog and [play with width](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/developer/model-driven-apps/clientapi/navigate-to-custom-page-examples#open-as-a-centered-dialog)

Comment: did you managed to solve the issue?

Comment: Hi @AnkUser,
Well, yes and no. I did not solve it. It was solved with the last Microsoft CRM update. (The one which hides the Advanced Find - Icon on certain parts of the system).

I cannot say what exactly got changed. What I know is that I have not changed anything on my solution at all.

Comment: Responding to your first comment:
I am calling the custom page via JS. It is a valid approach and has to work, since it is documented by Microsoft (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/developer/model-driven-apps/clientapi/reference/xrm-navigation/navigateto#custom-page)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not solve it. It was solved with the last Microsoft CRM update. (The one which hides the Advanced Find - Icon on certain parts of the system). I cannot say what exactly got changed. What I know is that I have not changed anything on my solution at all.